# Как выровнять placeholder в поле для ввода по верхней части?

Tags: html, css

```css
.form-main {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #1A2B48;
}

.form-main {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

form {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 0em;
}

.placeholder {
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 14px;
    letter-spacing: 0.06em;
    padding: 0 25px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    vertical-align: top;
}
input {
    width: 418px;
    height: 45px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(80, 145, 250, 0.7);
    margin-bottom: 17px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.message {
    height: 149px;
}

.checkbox-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
}

.checkbox {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    margin: 0;
}

input {
    width: 418px;
    height: 45px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(80, 145, 250, 0.7);
    margin-bottom: 17px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.checkbox {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    margin: 0;
}

.p-checkbox {
    max-width: 372px;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 0;
    color: rgba(26, 43, 72, 0.6);
}

.btn-form {
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 16px;
    align-items: center;
    letter-spacing: 0.06em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border: 0;
    background: #5091FA;
    padding: 15px 39px;
    width: 160px;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<form action="#" class="form-main">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Имя" class="placeholder" name="Ваше Имя" required="">
            <input type="email" placeholder="E-mail" class="placeholder" name="E-mail" required="">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Сообщение" class="placeholder message" name="   Сообщение" required="" style="padding-bottom: 0px !important;/* vertical-align:top; */text-align: -webkit-left;p;">

<div class="checkbox-wrapper">
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" checked=""> <p class="p-checkbox">Я выражаю свое согласие на обработку моих персональных данных в соответствие с  <a class="a-checkbox" href="#">Политикой обработки и защиты персональных данных</a></p>
</div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn-form">Отправить</button>
                    </form>
```

Что нужно применить в css, чтобы получить подсказку для ввода "Сообщение" сверху заданного поля? Приложил макет и что есть сейчас.

Буду рад помощи))
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: еще бы свой код приложили

Comment: Случайно [ничего](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1260635/377637) не забыли?

Comment: Добавил код! Выручайте

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.form-main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #1A2B48;
}

.form-main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

form {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 0em;
}

.placeholder {
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 0.06em;
  padding: 0 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(80, 145, 250, 0.7);
  margin-bottom: 17px;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 418px;
  height: 45px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(80, 145, 250, 0.7);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.message {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 418px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  min-height: 149px;
  color: rgba(26, 43, 72, 0.6);
  resize:none;
}

.checkbox-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.checkbox {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  margin: 0;
}

.p-checkbox {
  max-width: 372px;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 0;
  color: rgba(26, 43, 72, 0.6);
}

.btn-form {
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 16px;
  align-items: center;
  letter-spacing: 0.06em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: 0;
  background: #5091FA;
  padding: 15px 39px;
  width: 160px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<form action="#" class="form-main">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Имя" class="placeholder" name="Ваше Имя" required="" />
  <input type="email" placeholder="E-mail" class="placeholder" name="E-mail" required="" />
  <textarea placeholder="Сообщение" class="placeholder  message" name="Сообщение" required/></textarea>

  <div class="checkbox-wrapper">
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" checked="">
    <p class="p-checkbox">Я выражаю свое согласие на обработку моих персональных данных в соответствие с <a class="a-checkbox" href="#">Политикой обработки и защиты персональных данных</a></p>
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn-form">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

Как то так. Только размер шрифта выбрать

Comment: блин, а в чем причина была?

Comment: Там на сам деле много проблем, две основных - это то что для поля в котором планируется выводить много текста используется тег textarea и то что вы этому полю зафиксировали высоту, а этого делать не стоит. Вообще забудьте про тег height; Используйте min-height если она вам надо

Comment: BlackStar1991, спасибо огромное!! Сейчас буду разбираться)